# Google Calendar API V3 and Ajax : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api, google-calendar-api

**I'm getting lost with the new Google API V3 and JS calls (to perform Ajax requests).**

After registering an app in the console, added access to Calendar API, setting API client ID and public API key, added the domains I want to use the app with, I tried this :

```
var feedurl = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/8g7mhfnh0m4t0rrduvt01knnng%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?singleEvents=true&key=[MY_KEY]";
 $.get(feedurl,function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But it returns :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/8g7mhfnh0m4t0rrduvt01knnng%40group.ca…public/basic?singleEvents=true&key=[MY_KEY]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**What did I forget ?**

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Comment: you need to take auth token, there is a sample in url authentication https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors#Example2UsingtheURLparameter , did you tried gapi authentication to get your token?

Comment: Thank you for that doc, couldn't find it. So yet, I read it, but I don't seem to be able to make it work. See my edit.

Comment: I finally get it, but I have another question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153472/google-calendar-api-v3-events-from-a-particular-week