# Google Calendar API v3 : events from a particular week

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

**I'm currently getting events from Google Calendar API v3 (using Javascript).**

I was stuck on getting access to the API : [Google Calendar API V3 and Ajax : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151068/google-calendar-api-v3-and-ajax-no-access-control-allow-origin-header?noredirect=1#comment42797155_27151068)

And now, I'm a bit confused: I'm trying to get event list from few days (2012-07-31 to 2012-08-04, GMT+1), so here's what I tried :

```
gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3').then(function(data) {
                    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                       'calendarId': '[cal id]',
                         "timeMin": "2012-07-31T00:00:00+01:00",
                        "timeMax": "2012-08-05T00:00:00+01:00" 
                    });
                    request.execute(function(resp) {


                   for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                       console.log(resp.items[i]);
                   };


                  });
                });
```

But this request returns events with datetimes that doesn't seem to fit with what I requested: 2012-04-14T11:00:00+02:00, 2011-09-11

Any ideas ?

Comment: Weird thing : if I try with a more recent week (i.e. in 2014), it works as supposed.

Comment: It's usually caused by recurring events. If there are any instances of recurring events fitting into the range, they will be returned. Use singleevents=true

Answer (score 1):

You need to set 'singleEvents' to true which I believe returns individual instances of reoccurring events instead of the event group.

```
          gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3').then(function(data) {
                var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                   'calendarId': '[cal id]',
                    'singleEvents': true,
                     "timeMin": "2012-07-31T00:00:00+01:00",
                    "timeMax": "2012-08-05T00:00:00+01:00" 
                });
                request.execute(function(resp) {


               for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                   console.log(resp.items[i]);
               };


              });
            });
```