# Receive Google Calender events from 'ics' file and use it with FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, gcal

I've put my google calendar public and I'm trying to use the `ics` file but I'm getting a problem with `XMLHttpRequest`

What I've tried so far:

It works if I use my googleCalendarId and googleCalendarApiKey:

```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: '*************myApiKey**************',

        events: {
          googleCalendarId: 'chris.beckett@schoolspider.co.uk'
        },

        eventClick: function(event) {
            console.log(event.start);
            console.log(event.end);
            return false;
        }, 

        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }
    });
```

Then when I try and use the actual ics file like so:

```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({        
        events: {
          url: 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/chris.beckett%40schoolspider.co.uk/public/basic.ics'
        },

        eventClick: function(event) {
            console.log(event.start);
            console.log(event.end);
            return false;
        }, 

        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }
    });
```

It shows the following error in the console log:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/chris.beckett%40schoolspider.co.uk/public/basic.ics.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8887' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I've tried setting also the following:

```
//htaccess file
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
//php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//xhr 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: Take a look at the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151068/google-calendar-api-v3-and-ajax-no-access-control-allow-origin-header

Comment: @MarioLevrero - You have any idea why this isn't working for me?

Comment: Sorry, updated link. I think you need to be authenticated. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors#Example2UsingtheURLparameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the `ICS` file on to fullcalendar by using this method -

```
function icsToArray($paramUrl) {
        $icsFile = file_get_contents($paramUrl);

        $icsData = explode("BEGIN:", $icsFile);

        foreach($icsData as $key => $value) {
            $icsDatesMeta[$key] = explode("\n", $value);
        }

        foreach($icsDatesMeta as $key => $value) {
            foreach($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
                if ($subValue != "") {
                    if ($key != 0 && $subKey == 0) {
                        $icsDates[$key]["BEGIN"] = $subValue;
                    } else {
                        $subValueArr = explode(":", $subValue, 2);
                        $icsDates[$key][$subValueArr[0]] = $subValueArr[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $icsDates;
    }
```